# "Background-Image" not working with "height:auto" in CSS?

Tags: html, css, image, background

How do I go about doing this?

My HTML and CSS files are something like this:

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="author" content="Manpreet Singh (Mannie Cupquake)">
    <title>Blac Tree - Home</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function MM_swapImgRestore() {
        var i,x,a=document.MM_sr; for(i=0;a&&i<a.length&&(x=a[i])&&x.oSrc;i++) x.src=x.oSrc;
    }
    function MM_preloadImages() {
        var d=document; if(d.images){ if(!d.MM_p) d.MM_p=new Array();
        var i,j=d.MM_p.length,a=MM_preloadImages.arguments; for(i=0; i<a.length; i++)
        if (a[i].indexOf("#")!=0){ d.MM_p[j]=new Image; d.MM_p[j++].src=a[i];}}
    }

    function MM_findObj(n, d) {
        var p,i,x;  if(!d) d=document; if((p=n.indexOf("?"))>0&&parent.frames.length) {
            d=parent.frames[n.substring(p+1)].document; n=n.substring(0,p);}
        if(!(x=d[n])&&d.all) x=d.all[n]; for (i=0;!x&&i<d.forms.length;i++) x=d.forms[i][n];
        for(i=0;!x&&d.layers&&i<d.layers.length;i++) x=MM_findObj(n,d.layers[i].document);
        if(!x && d.getElementById) x=d.getElementById(n); return x;
    }

    function MM_swapImage() {
        var i,j=0,x,a=MM_swapImage.arguments; document.MM_sr=new Array; for(i=0;i<(a.length-2);i+=3)
        if ((x=MM_findObj(a[i]))!=null){document.MM_sr[j++]=x; if(!x.oSrc) x.oSrc=x.src; x.src=a[i+2];}
    }
</script>
</head>

<body background="../imgz/template/background.png" onLoad="MM_preloadImages('../imgz/buttons/sideHomeOver.png','../imgz/buttons/sideAboutOver.png','../imgz/buttons/sideContactOver.png','../imgz/buttons/sideTwitterOver.png','../imgz/buttons/sideFacebookOver.png','../imgz/buttons/sideYouTubeOver.png')">
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="headLogo">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="_content">
        <div class="sidebar">
            <br>
            <a href="../home/home.htm" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('homeButton','','../imgz/buttons/sideHomeOver.png',1)"><img src="../imgz/buttons/sideHome.png" alt="Home" id="homeButton" width="213" height="59" border="0"></a>
            <br>
            <br>
            <a href="../about/about.htm" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('aboutButton','','../imgz/buttons/sideAboutOver.png',1)"><img src="../imgz/buttons/sideAbout.png" alt="About" id="aboutButton" width="213" height="58" border="0"></a>
            <br>
            <br>
            <a href="../contact/contact.htm" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()"onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('contactButton','','../imgz/buttons/sideContactOver.png',1)"><img src="../imgz/buttons/sideContact.png" alt="Contact" id="contactButton" width="213" height="58" border="0"></a>
            <br>
            <br>
            <a href="#" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('twitterButton','','../imgz/buttons/sideTwitterOver.png',1)"><img src="../imgz/buttons/sideTwitter.png" alt="Twitter" id="twitterButton" width="60" height="60" border="0"></a>
            &nbsp;
            <a href="#" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('facebookButton','','../imgz/buttons/sideFacebookOver.png',1)"><img src="../imgz/buttons/sideFacebook.png" alt="Facebook" id="facebookButton" width="60" height="60" border="0"></a>
            &nbsp;
            <a href="#" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('youtubeButton','','../imgz/buttons/sideYouTubeOver.png',1)"><img src="../imgz/buttons/sideYouTube.png" alt="YouTube" id="youtubeButton" width="60" height="60" border="0"></a>
            <br>
            <br>
            <div class="address">
                1234 Test Road<br>
                West Chester, OH<br>
                45069-XX<br>
                (513) XXX-XXXX<br>
                info@blactree.org
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="gMap">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="contentWrapper">
            <div class="ribbon">
                <div class="ribbonText">
                    <div class="font1">
                        <br>
                    </div>
                    About
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas a justo ac lectus ornare mattis. Pellentesque volutpat cursus lectus non rhoncus.Maecenas pulvinar, tellus sed laoreet tristique, mauris felis luctus magna, in aliquam ante diam in lectus. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nam sed purus et ipsum auctor sollicitudin. Sed enim metus, mollis vel dignissim eu, vestibulum id libero. Donec convallis nulla malesuada orci viverra sagittis. Maecenas quis eleifend augue. Proin eu tortor quis lorem suscipit iaculis et feugiat mi. Nullam consequat nulla at nisi ultrices fermentum. Praesent scelerisque lacus et erat mattis condimentum at sed nunc. Cras facilisis nibh quis odio rhoncus lobortis.
                <br>
                <br>
                Vestibulum consequat leo ac enim faucibus vitae cursus leo condimentum. Pellentesque nec dui quis mauris elementum molestie. Donec pellentesque, leo accumsan tincidunt venenatis, urna lectus consequat sapien, sit amet feugiat turpis mi ut sem. Cras id metus et ipsum viverra bibendum eget nec urna. Vestibulum ac metus nec tellus suscipit dignissim vel pellentesque erat. Suspendisse in urna nulla. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Aenean feugiat feugiat aliquam. Duis fermentum massa lectus. Praesent ultricies tincidunt quam a sagittis. Pellentesque interdum dolor non diam ullamcorper suscipit. Proin tempus, est et cursus malesuada, diam lectus suscipit quam, non porttitor augue odio quis massa. Curabitur sit amet gravida lorem. Nullam venenatis, purus vitae egestas semper, arcu urna hendrerit felis, at molestie nisi orci eu urna. Sed venenatis, sapien rhoncus blandit sagittis, nunc felis mollis ipsum, eget aliquam felis turpis et magna. Morbi sapien enim, auctor id venenatis sed, pretium et arcu.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <br>
        <br>
        Blac Tree © All rights Reserved 2011-2012
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: typo_pro_sbi;
    src: url('font/typo_pro_sbi.ttf');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: typo_pro_eb;
    src: url('font/typo_pro_eb.ttf');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: bebas_neue;
    src: url('font/bebas_neue.otf');
}
.wrapper {
    height: auto;
    width: 950px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 35px;
}
.wrapper .header {
    background: url(../imgz/template/headerBg.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    height: 143px;
    width: 950px;
}
.wrapper .header .headLogo {
    background: url(../imgz/template/headerLogo.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    margin-left: 85px;
    height: 136px;
    width: 214px;
}
.wrapper ._content {
    background-image: url(../imgz/template/contentBg.png);
    height: auto;
    width: 950px;
}
.wrapper ._content .sidebar {
    float: left;
    height: auto;
    width: 314px;
    text-align: center;
}
.wrapper ._content .sidebar .homeButton,.wrapper ._content .sidebar .aboutButton,.wrapper ._content .sidebar .contactButton,.wrapper ._content .sidebar .twitterButton,.wrapper ._content .sidebar .facebookButton,.wrapper ._content .sidebar .youtubeButton {
    border: 0px;
}
.wrapper ._content .sidebar .address {
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 60px;
    font-family: typo_pro_sbi;
    color: #9c9c9c;
    font-size: 18px;
}
.wrapper ._content .sidebar .gMap {
    background-image: url(../imgz/buttons/gMap.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    text-align: center;
    height: 207px;
    width: 207px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.wrapper ._content .contentWrapper {
    background: url(../imgz/template/contentShadow.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    float: left;
    height: auto;
    width: 563px;
    color: #CCCCCC;
}
.wrapper ._content .contentWrapper .ribbon {
    background-image: url(../imgz/template/topRibbon.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    text-align: center;
    height: 113px;
    width: 560px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.wrapper ._content .contentWrapper .ribbon .ribbonText {
    font-family: typo_pro_eb;
    font-size: 32px;
    color: #abd7ff;
}
.wrapper ._content .contentWrapper .ribbon .ribbonText .font1 {
    font-size: 22px;
}
.wrapper ._content .contentWrapper .content {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    height: auto;
    width: 475px;
    overflow: auto;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-style: normal;
}
.wrapper .footer {
    background-image: url(../imgz/template/footerBg.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 80px;
    width: 950px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: bebas_neue;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #323232;
}
```

The "_content" class doesn't show the background image it is supposed to, can anyone explain to me why? The background image specified appears when I give the element a specific height, I tried using "min-height", but only minimum height specified displayed the background image, how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably because all its children are set to `float: left` which means you need to put something like `overflow: auto` on your `._content` to get it to recognize and wrap those floated elements (instead of being just 0 height).

**Further Explanation:** Floats need to be cleared in order for them to give height to their containing elements. There are various means of clearing floats, but the easiest is to set the `overflow` property on the containing element.